unexpected token: DISTINCT Spring Data
@Query("SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.estimateDate) AS MONTH, " +
            "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.estimateDate) AS YEAR, " +
            "e.status.id, " +
            "ROUND((SUM((i.squareFeet*i.depth)*i.price)-SUM(DISTINCT e.discount)), 2) AS TOTAL " +
            "FROM Estimate e " +
            "INNER JOIN Item i " +
            "ON i.estimate.id = e.id " +
            "WHERE e.seller.id = :sellerId " +
            "AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.estimateDate) = :year " +
            "GROUP BY MONTH, YEAR, e.status.id " +
            "ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.estimateDate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.estimateDate) DESC ")

Error: unexpected token: DISTINCT
The error is on SUM(DISTINCT e.discount). I removed the distinct and works but the values are wrong. I copied the sql on console and use direct to DB and everything works.

As I remember JPQL is used by default in Spring Data queries. So if you want execute some specific SQL constructions which work in your DB - set "nativeQuery" parameter in your Query annotation.
@Query(sql = "", nativeQuery = true)

But be careful SQL dialects may vary from DB to DB. It may not work for another database. Consider option to rewrite you query to fit JPQL.

The software support to many databases so I can't use native query.
